# Input an integer with placeholder in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, integer, placeholder, batchsize

I want to feed a `batch_size` integer as a placeholder in Tensorflow. But it does not act as an integer. Consider the following example:

```
import tensorflow as tf


max_length = 5
batch_size = 3

batch_size_placeholder = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32)

mask_0 = tf.one_hot(indices=[0]*batch_size_placeholder, depth=max_length, on_value=0., off_value=1.)
mask_1 = tf.one_hot(indices=[0]*batch_size, depth=max_length, on_value=0., off_value=1.)

# new session
with tf.Session() as sess:
    feed = {batch_size_placeholder : 3}

    batch, mask0, mask1 = sess.run([
                     batch_size_placeholder, mask_0, mask_1
    ], feed_dict=feed)
```

When I print the values of `batch`, `mask0` and `mask1` I have the following:

```
print(batch)
>>> array(3, dtype=int32)

print(mask0)
>>> array([[0., 1., 1., 1., 1.]], dtype=float32)

print(mask1)
>>> array([[0., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
           [0., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
           [0., 1., 1., 1., 1.]], dtype=float32)
```

Indeed I thought `mask0` and `mask1` must be the same, but it seems that Tensorflow does not treat `batch_size_placeholder` as an integer. I believe it would be a tensor, but is there anyway that I can use it as an integer in my computations?

Is there anyway I can fix this problem? Just FYI, I used `tf.one_hot` as just an example, I want to run train/validation during training in my code where I will need a lot of other computations with different values for `batch_size` in training and in validation steps.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pure python usage, `[0]*3` will be `[0,0,0]`. However, `batch_size_placeholder` is a placeholder, during the graph execution, it will be a tensor. `[0]*tensor` will be regarded as tensor multiplication. In your case, it will be a 1-d tensor which has 0 value. To correctly use `batch_size_placeholder`, you should create a tensor which has the same length as `batch_size_placeholder`.

```py
mask_0 = tf.one_hot(tf.zeros(batch_size_placeholder, dtype=tf.int32), depth=max_length, on_value=0., off_value=1.)
```

It will have the same result as `mask_1`.

A simple example to show the difference.

```py
batch_size_placeholder = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32)

a = [0]*batch_size_placeholder
b = tf.zeros(batch_size_placeholder, dtype=tf.int32)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run([a, b], feed_dict={batch_size_placeholder : 3}))

# [array([0], dtype=int32), array([0, 0, 0], dtype=int32)]
```